# When using VSCode SSH, where does VSCode move files deleted via the GUI?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I was cleaning up my workspace in VSCode's explorer and accidentally deleted an important file.
This was done on a remote machine via ssh connection and I was soon disconnected.

Normally, I know that you can Undo actions in the Explorer and restore files, but this is not working for me (presumably because of the disconnection).

My question is, where would these files have gone? Is there a way to find out where VSCode moves these files? I know it caches them somewhere since you can restore them just after deleting them.

I've seen people point to `~/.local/share/Trash` but this doesn't exist for me (again, working on a remote machine which I don't own).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: that machine does not have a repository or backup of this important file? You might have the luck I had discovering that unix rm does not have an undo

Comment: The partition I'm using is not backed up sadly. However I'm fairly sure that using rm is not equivalent to deleting files via VSCode's GUI since they can be restored (at least whilst still on the same session)

Comment: that is because VSC keeps the undo buffer for the file until the session is over. I have read you could set this to indefinite in some of the release notes